# Jquery Insert element before <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, insert

I am trying to insert a block element  Insert something  before another . I am not sure if I am using the right method but here is my code. Hope you guys can help. Thanks!

Jquery

```
$("#addMatch").click(function(){

    $("<td>New insert</td>").insertBefore("#addMatch").closest('tr');

    return false;   //this would insert the <td>New insert</td> before the               
                    //<td><input type="button" id="addMatch" name="addMatch" value="Add 
                    //Match" </td> but not <tr>
});
```

Html

```
<tr>
<td>some data</td>
</tr>

//can't tell how many tr would show before the last "addMatch" button. It's dynamic. 
// I want the <td>New insert</td> show up here.
    <tr> 
    <td><input type="button" id="addMatch" name="addMatch" value="Add Match" </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<td>` should always be in a `<tr>`.

I would probably make your function like this:

```
$("#addMatch").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr:first').before('<tr><td>New Insert</td></tr>');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Instead of `.parents('tr:first')`, there's `.closest('tr')` :)

Comment: Good one. Thanks! Yes, I think the closest is faster.

Comment: Good to know -- though curious on the logic behind it. closest has to check both parents and children, right? Parents only checks parents, and they both stop on the first one, is it just because of the way jQuery does it?

Comment: no i think parent is faster, because nothing to search before. but the closest do...